# How to create and keep serialport connection in Ruby on Rails, handle infinity loop to create model with new messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serial-port

I want to listening `SerialPort` and when message occurs then get or create `Log` model with id received from my device.

How to load once automatically `SerialPort` and keep established connection and if `key_detected?` in `listener` deal with `Log` model?

This is my autoloaded module in lib:

```
module Serialport
  class Connection
    def initialize(port = "/dev/tty0")
      port_str = port
      baud_rate = 9600
      data_bits = 8
      stop_bits = 1
      parity = SerialPort::NONE
      @sp = SerialPort.new(port_str, baud_rate, data_bits, stop_bits, parity)
      @key_parts = []
      @key_limit = 16 # number of slots in the RFID card.
      while true do
        listener
      end
      @sp.close
    end

    def key_detected?
      @key_parts << @sp.getc
      if @key_parts.size >= @key_limit
        self.key = @key_parts.join()
        @key_parts = []
        true
      else
        false
      end
    end

    def listener
      if key_detected?
        puts self.key
        # log = Log.find(rfid: self.key).first_or_create(rfid: self.key)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have written this in a comment, but it's a bit long... But I wonder if you could clarify your question, and I will update my answer as we go:

1. With all due respect to the Rails ability to "autoload", why not initialize a connection in an initialization file or while setting up the environment?

i.e., within a file in `you_app/config/initializers` called `serial_port.rb`:

```
SERIAL_PORT_CONNECTION = Serialport::Connection.new
```

2. Implementing an infinite loop within your Rails application will, in all probability, hang the Rails app and prevent it from being used as a web service.

   What are you trying to accomplish?

   If you just want to use active_record or active_support, why not just include these two gems in a separate script?

   Alternatively, consider creating a separate thread for the infinite loop (or better yet, use a reactor (They are not that difficult to write, but there are plenty pre-written in the wild, such as [Iodine](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) which I wrote for implementing web services)...

Here's an example for an updated listener method, using a separate thread so you call it only once:

```
def listener
   Thread.new do
     loop { self.key while key_detected? }
     # this will never be called - same as in your code.
     @sp.close
   end
end
```

Comment: I didn't realize that I have to create separate thread, thanks a lot!

Comment: @luzny Very Welcome :-)